# Spring Batch: Configuring service-activator

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I'm trying to add a service-activator in my Spring Batch .XML configuration file which sets requires-reply=false in my transformer method: FileMessageToJobRequestTransformer.

Here's the XML:

```
<int:transformer id="fileMessageToJobRequestTransformer"
                     input-channel="inboundFileChannel"
                     output-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel"
                     method="transform" >
        <bean class="com.distributedfinance.mbi.bai.transformer.FileMessageToJobRequestTransformer">
            <property name="job" ref="baiParseJob"/>
            <property name="fileParameterName" value="input.file.url"/>
        </bean>
        <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
    </int:transformer>

    <int:service-activator requires-reply="false" input-channel="inboundFileChannel" output-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel" ref="fileMessageToJobRequestTransformer"> </int:service-activator>
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#3': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#1' while setting bean property 'handler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#1': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found ambiguous parameter type [class java.lang.Long] for method match: [public void org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.setTrigger(org.springframework.scheduling.Trigger), public void org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.setErrorHandler(org.springframework.util.ErrorHandler), public void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setComponentName(java.lang.String), public void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext) throws org.springframework.beans.BeansException, public void org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint.setAutoStartup(boolean), public void org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(long), public void org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint.setTaskScheduler(org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler), public void org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint.setPhase(int), public void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.getComponentType(), public void org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.setTransactionSynchronizationFactory(org.springframework.integration.transaction.TransactionSynchronizationFactory), public final void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setBeanFactory(org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory)]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1584)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:253)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
        ... 23 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found ambiguous parameter type [class java.lang.Long] for method match: [public void org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.setTrigger(org.springframework.scheduling.Trigger), public void org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.setErrorHandler(org.springframework.util.ErrorHandler), public void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setComponentName(java.lang.String), public void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext) throws org.springframework.beans.BeansException, public void org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint.setAutoStartup(boolean), public void org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(long), public void org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint.setTaskScheduler(org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler), public void org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint.setPhase(int), public void org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.setBeanClassLoader(java.lang.ClassLoader), public void org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.setAdviceChain(java.util.List), public void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setChannelResolver(org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolver), public final void org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint.stop(java.lang.Runnable), public void org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.setTaskExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor), public void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setMessageBuilderFactory(org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilderFactory), public java.lang.String org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.getComponentType(), public void org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.setTransactionSynchronizationFactory(org.springframework.integration.transaction.TransactionSynchronizationFactory), public final void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setBeanFactory(org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory)]
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.isNull(Assert.java:92)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.findHandlerMethodsForTarget(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:446)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:192)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:136)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:131)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.<init>(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:57)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.<init>(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:37)
        at org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean.createMethodInvokingHandler(ServiceActivatorFactoryBean.java:57)
        at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractStandardMessageHandlerFactoryBean.createHandler(AbstractStandardMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:97)
        at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.createHandlerInternal(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:104)
        at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:46)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168)
        ... 28 more

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

UPDATE:

```
@Transformer
    public JobLaunchRequest transform(Message<File> message) {

        LOGGER.debug("File message: {}", message);
        String jobName = message.getPayload().getAbsolutePath().toString();

        if (jobName.contains(".gitignore"))
                return null;

        JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();

        jobParametersBuilder.addString(fileParameterName,
                "file://" + message.getPayload().getAbsolutePath());


        LOGGER.debug("Job params: {}", jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());

        Integer  pathDelimiterOffset = jobName.lastIndexOf('/');
        if (pathDelimiterOffset != -1) {
            String fileName = jobName.substring(pathDelimiterOffset+1);
            String archiveDirectoryName =  "bai/archive/";
            String archivePathName =  archiveDirectoryName.concat(fileName);
            File f = new File(archivePathName);

            // If the file exists in the bai/archive directory - assume it has already been processed - SKIP IT!  This is not a as reliable as querying Spring Batch tablle batch_execution_params... which will be done next.
            if (f.exists() && !f.isDirectory())
                return null;
        }

        try {
            return new JobLaunchRequest(job, jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException) {
                LOGGER.debug("Exception Handler: JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException - Job params: {}", jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

SftpBaiParserJobBridge-context.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
           xmlns:batch-int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch-integration"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch-integration
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch-integration/spring-batch-integration.xsd">

        <!-- The bridge between SFTP spring integration to BAI parse spring batch job -->

        <int:channel id="outboundJobRequestChannel"/>
        <int:channel id="jobLaunchReplyChannel">
            <int:queue/>
            <int:interceptors>
                <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
            </int:interceptors>
        </int:channel>

        <!-- When getting a new BAI file, transform into spring batch job request -->
        <int:transformer id="fileMessageToJobRequestTransformer"
                         input-channel="inboundFileChannel"
                         output-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel"
                               method="transform" >
            <bean class="com.distributedfinance.mbi.bai.transformer.FileMessageToJobRequestTransformer">
                <property name="job" ref="baiParseJob"/>
                <property name="fileParameterName" value="input.file.url"/>
            </bean>
            <int:poller fixed-rate="60000" max-messages-per-poll="100"/>
        </int:transformer>

        <!-- Gateway to launch the BAI parse spring batch job -->
        <batch-int:job-launching-gateway request-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel"
                                         reply-channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel">
        </batch-int:job-launching-gateway>

        <int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" level="WARN"
                                     logger-name="com.distributedfinance.mbi.bai.job"/>
    </beans>
```

SftpInboundReceive-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-sftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp/spring-integration-sftp.xsd">

    <!-- Create an inbound channel adapter to receive the BAI files via SFTP -->

    <import resource="SftpSession-context.xml"/>

    <int:channel id="inboundFileChannel">
        <int:queue/>
    </int:channel>

    <int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInboundAdapter"
            auto-startup="true"
            channel="inboundFileChannel"
            session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
            local-directory="${bai.sftp.local-dir}"
            remote-directory="${bai.sftp.remote-dir}"
            auto-create-local-directory="true"
            preserve-timestamp="true"
            delete-remote-files="${bai.sftp.delete}">
        <int:poller cron="${bai.sftp.cron}" max-messages-per-poll="10"/>
    </int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>


</beans>
```

BaiParserJob.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/spring-util.xsd">

    <bean name="jobParametersIncrementer" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer"/>

    <!-- BATCH-2351 workaround -->
    <bean id="stepScope" class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope">
        <property name="autoProxy" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <batch:job id="baiParseJob" incrementer="jobParametersIncrementer">
        <batch:step id="baiParseStep" next="baiArchive">
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                <batch:chunk reader="baiItemReader"
                             processor="baiItemProcessor"
                             writer="baiItemWriter"
                             commit-interval="1"/>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
        <batch:step id="baiArchive">
            <batch:tasklet ref="fileArchivingTasklet"/>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="baiItemReader" class="com.distributedfinance.mbi.bai.reader.MultiLineBaiItemReader"
            scope="step">
        <property name="delegate" ref="flatFileItemReader"/>
        <property name="baiFileFieldSetMapper">
            <bean class="com.distributedfinance.mbi.bai.mapper.BaiFileFieldSetMapper"/>
        </property>
        <property name="baiGroupFieldSetMapper">
            <bean class="com.distributedfinance.mbi.bai.mapper.BaiGroupFieldSetMapper"/>
        </property>
        <property name="baiAccountFieldSetMapper">
            <bean class="com.distributedfinance.mbi.bai.mapper.BaiAccountFieldSetMapper">
                <property name="parser">
                    <bean class="com.distributedfinance.mbi.bai.mapper.BaiTypeParser"/>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="baiTransactionFieldSetMapper">
            <bean class="com.distributedfinance.mbi.bai.mapper.BaiTransactionFieldSetMapper"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="flatFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="resource" value="#{jobParameters['input.file.url']}"/>
        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer"/>
                </property>
                <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PassThroughFieldSetMapper"/>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="baiItemProcessor" class="com.distributedfinance.mbi.bai.processor.BaiItemProcessor">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="accountLookup"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1">
            <bean class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
                <constructor-arg value="yyMMddHHmmss"/>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="baiItemWriter" class="com.distributedfinance.mbi.bai.writer.BaiItemWriter"/>

    <bean id="accountLookup" class="com.distributedfinance.mbi.bai.lookup.AccountLookup"/>

    <bean id="fileArchivingTasklet" class="com.distributedfinance.mbi.bai.tasklet.FileArchivingTasklet">
        <property name="downloadFileKey" value="input.file.url"/>
        <property name="archiveDirectory" value="${bai.sftp.archive-dir}"/>
        <property name="purgeDays" value="${bai.sftp.purge-days}"/>
    </bean>
 </beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference the `fileMessageToJobRequestTransformer` bean from a `service-activator`; the framework doesn't know which method to call. The actual transformer bean is wrapped in a consumer bean.

It looks like you don't need the service activator at all - you already have the transformer subscribed to that channel `input-channel="inboundFileChannel"`.

With your configuration you have two consumers on that channel - the transformer and the service activator.

**EDIT**

Transformers are always expected to return a reply; since your class might or might not return a reply, it's not really a transformer (in the strictest sense), it's a service.

Simply use

```
<int:service-activator id="fileMessageToJobRequestTransformer"
                 input-channel="inboundFileChannel"
                 output-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel"
                 requires-reply="false"
                 method="transform" >
    <bean class="com.distributedfinance.mbi.bai.transformer.FileMessageToJobRequestTransformer">
        <property name="job" ref="baiParseJob"/>
        <property name="fileParameterName" value="input.file.url"/>
    </bean>
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
</int:service-activator>
```

Comment: I added 'skip logic' to my transformer - fileMessageToJobRequestTransformer which returns null if the file has already been processed.  I got an exception when returning null from the transformer, so I tried adding requires-reply="false" in the service-activator.  How do I configure this so my transformer can return null?  Thanks!

Comment: Then you just need to invoke your bean as a service-activator, not a transformer; see my edit.

Comment: That helped!  Do I need to also change the annotation - currently "@Transformer" (see UPDATE above).  Another question (tangential to original question) - Am I catching the JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException correctly (it doesn't appear to work).

Comment: You don't need the annotation at all when configuring directly using XML - that's only used when using annotation-driven configuration. Creating a `JobLaunchRequest` does not throw that exception (it doesn't even look at the repository). That exception is thrown when you actually launch the job; you will need to add error handling to your integration flow to catch that exception. With your configuration it will just be logged; if you want to handle it some other way, add an `error-channel` to the `poller`.

Comment: Changing the transformer to service-activator while avoiding the requiresReply exception (e.g. - 15:42:29.184 [task-scheduler-10] ERROR o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyRequiredException: No reply produced by handler 'fileMessageToJobRequestTransformer', and its 'requiresReply' property is set to true.), broke the polling logic - I'm not sure why.  How do I add the error-channel to the poller?  Can I skip already processed files in the error-channel?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "broke the polling logic". `error-channel="foo"` then add a service-activator to consume from foo and discard the failures.

Comment: 'broke the polling logic' -> sftp no longer retrieved files from the remote server.  As soon as I changed 'service-activator' back to 'transformer', sftp started working again.

Comment: That makes no sense unless there's something else in the picture. Please edit the question to show the complete flow. If there's a mid-flow gateway it needs a timeout.

Comment: Added code for: BaiParserJob.xml, SftpInboundReceive-context.xml and SftpInboundReceive-context.xml (above).

Comment: Since `inboundFileChannel` is a queue channel, I find it hard to believe that any changes to the downstream flow can have any effect on the sftp poller. The poller and the downstream flow are completely independent tasks. The poller on the transformer pulls files from that channel; the transformer and service activator are both completely passive components (made active by the poller) when the service returns null the second poller task ends immediately and the next poll will grab the next file (if present in the queue).    If polling truly stops, use jstack to get a thread dump.

Comment: I forgot to change the annotation from atTransformer to atServiceActivator (e.g. atServiceActivator
    public JobLaunchRequest transform(Message<File> message).  I believe it's working properly now... (still monitoring).